# Bounded waiting issue in test_and_set

Tags: synchronization, atomic

```
while (1) {
      while (TestAndSet(&lock));  /* busy wait */

        /* critical section */

      lock = false;

        /* non-critical section */
    }
```

How does the above code snippet exactly suffer from bounded waiting problem i.e some processes may have to wait indefinitely to enter their critical section? Its not really clear to me why Peterson's solution does not suffer from the same problem? Can anybody please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Peterson's algorithm guarantees progress -- by rotating the `turn` variable, it ensures that turns are spread across the contending processors. Check-and-set does not have this effect, and can allow a single processor to hog the lock to the exclusion of all others.